# Array question, What`s that type? Why it can run in the code?

Tags: python, arrays, matplotlib, types

```
Nor = [80,50,150,100,50,70,100,40]
Mid = [150,70,200,120,50,70,100,50]
Sou = [20,100,120,130,100,100,100,50]
Ove = [10,5,10,0,100,70,100,40]
x = np.arange(1,9,1)
width = 0.17

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,5))

rects1 = ax.bar(x - 1.5*width ,Nor, width, label='Nor')
rects2 = ax.bar(x - width/2,Mid, width, label='Mid')
rects3 = ax.bar(x + width/2,Sou, width, label='Mid')
rects4 = ax.bar(x + 1.5*width,Ove, width, label='Mid')



ax.set(xlabel='Season', ylabel='Market share %',
       title='Every season market share')
plt.grid()

legend = ax.legend(loc='upper left', shadow=True, fontsize='x-large',prop={'size': 8})


fig.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Why line 6  `x = np.arange(1,9,1)` can not be `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]`, what`s the difference ? I think is the difference for data type, but why line 6 can work in this code?

Comment: Have you looked into what numpy is? That what the `np` is referring to.

Comment: What did you get when you checked `type(x)` for each case?

Answer (score 0):

While `x = np.arange(1,9,1)` generates a numpy array, `x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` is just a list.
You can see the difference in the datatype:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(1,9,1)
print(type(x))
x = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
print(type(x))
```

Output:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'list'>
```

When you try replacing `np.arange(1,9,1)` with `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]` you will get the following error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'list' and 'float'

This is because you can only subtract an number from an array. In an list you would have to subtract the number from each element individually.